# Eclipse Debugging Error: Check Debug Command, Debug

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I am debugging using eclipse

`Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)`

`Build id: 20200910-1200`

on a java application deployed in a tomcat server.

I was able to attached, listen to the tomcat instance. Whenever I trigger a specific method on a class where I target a specific line.

[image]

i get the following error.

[image]

Did anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a problem that looked just like yours. It was causes by compatibility problems between Eclipse 2020-09 and the Kotlin Plugin. There are more details here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=567081

Do you have the Kotlin Plugin installed? If yes, It might be worth a try to remove it, at least to check if it is the cause.

Comment: yeah I had kotlin plugin, I tried re install eclipse from fresh without any plugin and it works. So I guess you may be right, tho I dont know which plugin for me causes an issue.